# Minor clipping on expanded vote counts

Tags: bug, design, css

The answer to ([How to make trigger code execute only for a specific application?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44752/how-to-make-trigger-code-execute-only-for-a-specific-application)) demonstrate some clipping that is occurring when you expand vote counts. The following shows two shots at actual size, and then the +10 zoomed in using Photoshop (not the browser controls).

[image]

Non 10k-ers will not be able to confirm the issue on the deleted post, but should see the issue on the answer that is still present. It's a minor issue but I'm really OCD about this stuff (and I'm sure plenty of my fellow database professionals are as well).

This issue seems to affect our styling but not SO proper's. Also note I am observing this in Chrome 27.0.1453.116 on Mac OS 10.9.

Comment: +1 for nice freehand marks

Answer (score 4):

I think this is client-side.  Below is a blowed-up screenshot from chrome of the same section:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I also don't see clipping when taking a screenshot at 100% and zooming in:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I'm in Chrome too, but not on Windows... and I don't see the clipping if I zoom in using the browser, but I do at 100% and when I zoom a screen shot after the fact...

Comment: Let me try that too, then...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Still looks good to me, see the SS

Comment: Yeah I seem to be getting a slightly thicker/bolder typeface on Mac than you are on Windows.

Comment: no clipping on Ubuntu/Chrome

Comment: Can you post a larger version? I'm not sure I understand.